# Google Shortening API returns null if URL to be shortened is long i.e more than 2000-3000 characters

Tags: google-api-client, url-shortener

Recently I have an issue in my project that I need to shorten a URL . I am using Google shortener API .(https://goo.gl)

For small strings, it is working fine and returning correct short URL .

But for Strings having large characters shortened URL is returning null .

So I have 2 questions :
1.) Is any character limit up to which google shortener API is able to convert long urls into short urls .
2.) If 1.) is the case please let me know suggestion so I am able to get short URL from long string also as it is critical for my project .

Suggestions and Help will be very grateful .

Regards,
Deepak

Comment: Note that URLs of that length or likely to fail even if google does it correctly. Browsers implement limits. Also I would say if your URLs are that long you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Just use short identifiers and retrieve the data based on this id.

Comment: I need to preserve deep linking so if make all selection in checkboxes , deep linked url will be >2000 characters and google api returns null while shortening .   So if any way to increase number of permissible characters . All coding is done in Backend and all long data is in backend with no interaction to browser . Simply google api can't parse it .

Comment: ["Just use short identifiers and retrieve the data based on this id"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283567/google-shortening-api-returns-null-if-url-to-be-shortened-is-long-i-e-more-than?noredirect=1#comment67825550_40283567)

Comment: As in just don't store data in the URL, but in some persistent serverside thing. And retrieve it when it is being requested.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your inputs . Actually, issue is whatever data I will be saving in id are tags and tags take large spaces . If I just store tags 200 tags it will take 3000 characters .  But you are correct if browser issue i need to make these tags very short and pass , but still 2000 characters is very small .

Comment: No it is not. You just shouldn't use URLs as a storage mechanism.